# Order of zero at infinity for a polynomial in the extended complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials

I am studying for a Complex Analysis exam, and my professor proposed an exercise as preparation: in the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$, what is the order of vanishing of a polynomial $P(z)$ at $z=\infty$?

I would think that it is $0$ since $P(\infty) = \infty$. Can anyone explain if this is correct or not?

As a follow-up, what if we have a rational function $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$? I think by the same logic this would be $0$ if $deg(P) \geq deg(Q)$, but I am not sure what it would be if $deg(P) < deg(Q)$. Perhaps $deg(Q) - deg(P)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(z)=a_0+a_1z+...+a_nz^n$ and $Q(z):=P(1/z)$.

Then, by definition,

$P$ has a zero at $ \infty$ iff $Q$ has a zero at $0$

From $Q(z)=a_0 +\frac{a_1}{z}+...+\frac{a_n}{z^n}$ we get

$P$ has a zero at $ \infty$ iff $a_0=a_1=...=a_n=0$

Answer (score 1):

This question of seing $\infty$ as a point of the extended complex plane isn't trivial.

- $f(z)$ has a pole at $\infty$ of order $k$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f(1/z)$ has a pole of order $k$ at $z=0$. For example $z^2$ has a pole of order $2$, while $\frac{1}{z(z^3+4)}+\frac{1}{z^5}$ has a zero of order $4$.

  The only entire functions having a pole at $\infty$ are the polynomials (proof : $\frac{1}{f(1/z)}$ has a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) at $z=0$)

  For a polynomial, it is clear that the order of its pole at $\infty$ is also its number of zeros (counted with multiplicity).

  More generally, for a rational function $\#\text{poles} - \#\text{zeros} =0$. An other way for seeing it is by looking at $\int_\gamma \frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}dz$ seen as a contour integral on the Riemann sphere.
- There is also the [residue at $\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)#On_compact_Riemann_surfaces) which is defined by $Res(f(z),\infty) = Res(\frac{f(1/z)}{-z^2},0)$,  allowing us to write $\sum_{f(\rho) = \infty} Res(f(z),\rho)= 0$
- The Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C}_\infty=\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\} $ is a [compact Riemann surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Riemann_surface). It means that a function that is [holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ is necessarily constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)#On_compact_Riemann_surfaces).

  If a function is meromorphic on $C_\infty$, then by compactness it has a finite number of poles and zeros, and it is a rational function (a quotient of polynomials).
- Meromorphic functions can be thought as analytic functions $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}_\infty$
- ...

Comment: Will the order of the pole be the same as the order of vanishing/order of the zero?

Comment: @Captain what zero ? and (in the context of meromorphic functions) a pole of order $k$ is the same as a zero of order $-k$